# Wildfly 8.2 SSO logout issue across apps in the same domain

Tags: java, single-sign-on, wildfly, wildfly-8, jdbcrealm

I have some strange behaviour, and I am not sure why. I have two apps that work well in Tomcat 7, but do not behave correctly in Wildfly 8.2 and 9Beta2.

1. In Tomcat, I can log in on one app, go to the 2nd app and I can see my login state is correct, log out in the 2nd app, return to the 1st app, and I am logged out there. This is correct.
2. In Tomcat, I can log in on one app, go to the 2nd app and I can see my login state is correct, return to the 1st app, log out in the 1st app, return to the 2nd app, and I am logged out there. This is correct.
3. In Wildfly, I log in to the 1st app, go to the 2nd app and I can see my login state is correct, log out of the 2nd app, return to the 1st app, but I am still logged in. Incorrect.
4. In Wildfly, I log in to the 1st app, go to the 2nd app and I can see my login state is correct, return to the 1st app, log out of the 1st app, go to the 2nd app, and I am logged out there as well. Correct.

Why does Wildfly fail the first test (3. above)?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Here are some of the extracts from my files:

From standalone.xml

```
<security-realm name="DataSourceRealm">
    <authentication>
        <jaas name="app"/>
    </authentication>
</security-realm>

<security-domain name="app" cache-type="default">
     <authentication>
         <login-module code="Database" flag="requisite">
              <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
              <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="jdbc/icedb"/>
              <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select PASSWORD from WSV_USR_PRFL_DEF where USR_PRFL_DEF_ID=?"/>
              <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select USR_GRP_DEF_ID, 'Roles' from WSV_USR_GRP_MAP where USR_PRFL_DEF_ID = ?"/>
              <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
          </login-module>
          <login-module code="RoleMapping" flag="requisite">
               <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/app.properties"/>
               <module-option name="replaceRole" value="false"/>
          </login-module>
      </authentication>
 </security-domain>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:2.0">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">    
                 <single-sign-on path="/"/>
                 .....
```

from the various applications (WAR) jboss-web.xml:

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/APPNAME</context-root>
    <security-domain flushOnSessionInvalidation="true">app</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

From my logout.java:

```
@WebServlet(name="logout", urlPatterns={"/lo.xhtml"}, loadOnStartup=2)
public class Logout extends HttpServlet{

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (request.getSession(false) != null) {
        HttpSession ses = request.getSession(false);
        ses.invalidate(); // remove session.
    }
    request.logout();
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());
}
```

}

Comment: Take a look in https://developer.jboss.org/thread/242039?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: I have seen that, but is only works if the app you logged in from is the one you log out from. Very strange behaviour. If you notice, my code extract does as they recommend. They also mention it would be fixed in 8.2. So I tried bith 8.2 and 9